# java program to validate the enumerations in xml and xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd

**I need to detect the errors in the enumerations**.

This is my code to validate the XML and XSD with enumerations but I get a lot of errors. Can someone give me some feedback about the error messages (printed by the java program)?

**This is the document I am trying to validate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<person name="avinash" age="27" gender="male"> 
    <address type="email">xgjjkk@gmail.com</address> 
    <address type="phone">khkhlll</address> 
    <address type="company">jgjhgjhgk</address>  
</person>
```

**This is my Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/persondetails" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/persondetails" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
    <element name="person"> 
        <complexType> 
            <sequence> 
                <element name="address"> 
                    <complexType> 
                        <attribute name="type"> 
                            <simpleType> 
                                <restriction base="string"> 
                                    <enumeration value="email"></enumeration> 
                                    <enumeration value="phone"></enumeration> 
                                    <enumeration value="company"></enumeration> 
                                </restriction> 
                            </simpleType> 
                        </attribute> 
                    </complexType> 
                </element> 
            </sequence> 
            <attribute name="name" type="string"></attribute>  
            <attribute name="age" type="int"></attribute>  
            <attribute name="gender" type="string"></attribute> 
        </complexType> 
    </element> 
</schema>
```

**Java program**

```
package com.pack.group;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource; 
import javax.xml.validation.Schema; 
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory; 
import javax.xml.validation.Validator; 

public class Error { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource("D:/project/enum1.xsd")); 
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator(); 
        validator.validate(new StreamSource("D:/project/enum.xml")); 
    } 
}
```

**And these are the errors I got**

> Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1:
>   Cannot find the declaration of element 'person'.  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1916)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)

Comment: You'll need to add in what Java errors you are getting into your question so people can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema declares `address` as an *empty* element (it can only contain attributes), so your instance will not validate.

If you wish to allow simple text content inside the `address` element, you need to declare it differently, placing the attribute declarations as an extension of the simple content of the element:

```
<element name="address"> 
    <complexType> 
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="string">
                <attribute name="type"> 
                    <simpleType> 
                        <restriction base="string"> 
                            <enumeration value="email"></enumeration> 
                            <enumeration value="phone"></enumeration> 
                            <enumeration value="company"></enumeration> 
                        </restriction> 
                    </simpleType> 
                </attribute> 
            </extension>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType> 
</element>
```

You instance will still not validate because you only allow *one* child `address` element. You can change that using `maxOccurs="unbounded"` (or some fixed value such as `maxOccurs="3"`):

```
<element name="person"> 
    <complexType> 
        <sequence> 
            <element name="address" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
....
```

Comment: after i validate it after the changes said by @helderdarocha
i get an error ***cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'person'.***